# Android Studio: failed to find style 'checkboxStyle' in current theme

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to create Android app with Android Studio. While using checkboxes got trouble: no actual checkbox appeared. Only its' text.
Got message about missing styles.(Link to the screenshot is below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tzdf.png

How can I handle it?

`XML file`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pizza"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/cbPizza"
        android:checked="false"
        android:allowUndo="false" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cbHamburger" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="HamBurger"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`Manifest` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alesto.checkbox" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you please add your xml.!

Comment: added activity and manifest xmls @AkshayShinde

Comment: On the upper side of window choose App theme. And no worries about rendering. still you can run your app.

Comment: @AkshayShinde thanks a lot. Really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the upper side of window choose App theme. And no worries about rendering. still you can run your app.